# optimize sql query with DISTINCT

Tags: sql

I have a query with several inner joins on tables attr, data and extradata, as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) a.ID 
   FROM attr AS a 
       INNER JOIN data AS X ON a.ID = X.ID
       INNER JOIN extradata XA ON X.dataID = XA.dataID    
   WHERE X.data = 'condition1' 
     and XA.dataID NOT IN (SELECT dataID FROM extradata WHERE XA.additionaldata = 'condition2')
```

For something that is returning only the top 10 (`TOP(10)`) records, the query takes around 15 minutes to complete. When I replace:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) a.ID
```

With

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) *
```

The query takes only seconds. Also, I probably should rewrite the following part:

```
and XA.dataID NOT IN (SELECT dataID FROM extradata WHERE XA.additionaldata = 'condition2')
```

Because when I comment out this line, the query again takes only seconds. So far, I tried:

```
and NOT EXISTS (SELECT dataID FROM extradata WHERE XA.additionaldata = 'condition2')
```

But no use, the query still takes a lot of time. FYI, all tables contain around 1 million records each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the query by removing two extra joins and using `not exists`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) X.ID 
FROM data X
WHERE X.data = 'condition1' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT dataID
                  FROM extradata ed
                  WHERE XA.additionaldata = 'condition2' AND ed.dataId = X.dataID
                 );
```

This might be sufficient.  For this query, you can then start using indexes.  I would suggest `data(data, dataID, ID)` and `extradata(dataID, additionaldata)`.

This assumes that the joins are not used for filtering, at least not in a relevant way.  If so, you can add additional conditions in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) X.ID 
FROM data X
WHERE X.data = 'condition1' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM extradata ed
                  WHERE XA.additionaldata = 'condition2' AND ed.dataId = X.dataID
                 ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM attr a WHERE a.ID = X.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! your first suggestion returns faster results, so that's good news for me :) And yeah, I think I should add the indexes like you mentioned